# Crash on iterating over an image using Mat::at

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to the c++ interface and running out of ideas about this code:

```
//buffer : VideoCapture >> cvtColor >> Canny

for(int i=0;i<buffer.rows;i++) //search for edges
{
    for (int j=0 ;j<buffer.cols;j++)
    {
        Vec3b pixel=buffer.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
    }
}
```

runs fine in debug mode but crashing at some point (i=479, j=448) in release.(oh and can't catch any exception... of course...)

but

```
Vec3b pixel=buffer.at<Vec3b>(1,1000);
```

works in elease even if my image(buffer) is 640*480.

I think i am missing something. I'd be thankfull to you guys if you can get some sense out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `Vec3b` iterator which is supposed to be used on 3 channel images. You are using a single channel image, to iterate such an image you have to replace `Vec3b` with `uchar`.

Comment: oh ok how stupid! The 

"C++: void cvtColor(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code, int dstCn=0 )¶
[...]
dst – Destination image of the same size and depth as src . "

troubled me but great thank you bamboon !